# Using SQL I need to parse name from column and make new columns out of it

Tags: sql, parsing, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in SQL that has a name and various other items in it. I'm trying to figure out how to parse the name out and create new columns for it. I want to add two new columns and the new columns would then have first name and last name.

Example

```
APPLES-JST-JN-2022-07-22:BANANA:MELISSA:CUMBERBACH
```

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract parts of a delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to extract parts of a string that use a delimiter to separate values.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD FirstName VARCHAR(100), ADD LastName VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE yourTable 
SET FirstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn, ':', -2), ':', 1),
    LastName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(yourColumn, ':', -1);
```

Replace `yourTable` and `yourColumn` with the actual table and column names.